# Compare between TFS and SourceSafe

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

We recently moved all of our source to TFS from SourceSafe but forgot to get the latest versions from SourceSafe before doing so! Huge mistake.

Is there a way that I can compare files in SourceSafe with those in TFS to view the differences or any solution?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't compare between the two systems.

But you can create a TFS workspace and do a Get Latest into it, then do the equivalent in SourceSafe, then compare the two disk versions of all the files you like. If your diff tool allows it, you can even do folder comparisons.

Comment: I'd recommend getting the initial checkin for tfs rather than the latest, that way you can see just the missing bits rather than new work in tfs.

Comment: Afaik when you migrate from VSS to TFS several changesets will be created. But you are right - find last version that was migrated from VSS and get it on disk (tf get /v:xxx) and then compare with VSS (tf folderdiff)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to get a checkout of the initial checkin of TFS and a latest version from SourceSafe.
Then check out all files for edit in TFS and paste over the latest version from SourceSafe.

This will give a list of pending changes that should give the difference between the two.

Be very careful with this, as it can break a lot of things.